# How can I loop with multiple conditional statements in OpenRefine (GREL)

Tags: json, geocoding, openrefine, grel

I am geocoding using OpenRefine. I pulled data from OpenStreetMaps to my dataset[structure of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auKFu.png)

I am adding a "column based on this column" for the coordinates.I want to check that the display_name contains "Rheinland-Pfalz" and if it does, I want to extract the latitude and longitude,i.e.  pair.lat + ',' + pair.lon. I want to do this iteratively but I don't know how. I have tried the following:

if(display_name[0].contains("Rheinland-Pfalz"), with(value.parseJson()[0], pair, pair.lat + ',' + pair.lon),"nothing")

but I want to do this for each index [0] up to however many there are. I would appreciate if anyone could help.

Edit: Thanks for your answer b2m.
How would I extract the display_name corresponding to the coordinates that we get. I want the output to be display_name lat,lon for each match (i.e. contains "Rheinland-Pfalz", because I have a different column containing a piece of string that I want to match with the matches generated already.

For example, using b2m's code and incorporating the display_name in the output we get 2 matches:

Schaumburg, Balduinstein, Diez, Rhein-Lahn-Kreis, Rheinland-Pfalz, Deutschland 50.33948155,7.9784308849342604
Schaumburg, Horhausen, Flammersfeld, Landkreis Altenkirchen, Rheinland-Pfalz, Deutschland 52.622319,14.5865283

For each row, I have another string in a different column. Here the entry is "Rhein-Lahn-Kreis". I want to filter the two matches above to only keep those containing my string in the other column. In this case "Rhein-Lahn-Kreis" but the other column entry is different for each row. I hope this is clear and I would greatly appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we have the following json data

```json
[
    {"display_name": "BW", "lat": 0, "lon": 1},
    {"display_name": "NRW 1", "lat": 2, "long": 3},
    {"display_name": "NRW 2", "lat": 4, "lon": 5}
]
```

You can extract the combined elements `lat` and `long` with [forEach](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/grel#foreache1-v-e2) and [filter](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/grel#filtere1-v-e-test) using the following GREL expression e.g. in the [Add column based on this column](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/columnediting#add-column-based-on-this-column) dialog.

```js
forEach(
    filter(
        value.parseJson(), geodata, geodata.display_name.contains("NRW")
    ), el, el.lat + "," + el.lon)
.join(";")
```

This will result in a new field with the value `2,3;4,5`.

You can then [split the new multi valued field](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/cellediting#split-multi-valued-cells) on the semicolon ";" to obtain separated values (`2,3` and `4,5`).

Another approach would be to split the JSON Array elements into separate rows, avoiding the `forEach` and `filter` functions.

Comment: Thank you very much - that worked well. Would you mind taking a look at my edited post as well, please?

Comment: Ok, you extended your problem by adding a second question, which does not help the comprehensibility of your original question. As far as I understand your addition you want to compare the content of one column with the content of the other column... like `value.contains(row.cells["Comparison Columns Name"].value)`. You can use this expression in a "Custom Facet" or to create a indicator column with boolean values, or wrap it in an if-clause, ...